# Excel VBA - Prepare report from data with all items and subtotals

Tags: vba, excel

looking forward to someone helping me with this thing I have been trying to achieve for a few days in Excel using VBA.

So I am trying to generate a report/packing list for items received for a particular delivery. I have been able to populate some of the items but not when I would like to get the items for a specific document number with the sub-total.

So I start off with a sheet where I enter the document number, for which I want to generate the report:

[Generate Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7URna.png)

Then I want a macro to run where it will gather data from two other sheets and finally populate the PackingList sheet.

[DocumentData Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1vka.png)

[ProductData Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMboP.png)

[PackingList Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpqkl.png)

Below is the code I have so far, which is probably not the best:

```
Sub GeneratePackingList()

    DocumentNumber = Worksheets("Generate").Range("B1").Value
    Worksheets("PackingList").Activate
    Range("DocumentNumber").Value = DocumentNumber

    Dim ws
    Dim ws2
    Dim rng

    Dim dateScheduled
    Dim dateStarted
    Dim dateEnded

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Generate")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DocumentData")
    Set rng = ws1.Range("B1")

        On Error GoTo myErrorHandler
        purchaseOrderNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, Range("DocumentData"), 3, False)
        dateScheduled = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, Range("DocumentData"), 4, False)
        dateStarted = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, Range("DocumentData"), 5, False)
        dateEnded = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, Range("DocumentData"), 6, False)
        receivedFrom = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, Range("DocumentData"), 7, False)
        personnelReceiving = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, Range("DocumentData"), 8, False)
        driverName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, Range("DocumentData"), 9, False)

myErrorHandler:
            If Err.Number = 1004 Then
                MsgBox "Value not found"
            End If


    Range("DateScheduled").Value = dateScheduled
    Range("DateStarted").Value = dateStarted
    Range("DateEnded").Value = dateEnded
    Range("ReceivedFrom").Value = receivedFrom
    Range("PersonnelReceiving").Value = personnelReceiving
    Range("DriverName").Value = driverName
    Range("PurchaseOrderNumber").Value = purchaseOrderNumber

    ActiveSheet.Range("StartingRow").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select




'
End Sub
```

Mainly need help with populating the items and their values, and then subtotals with a grand total. However any help would be appreciated to make this code neat.

Looking forward to the responses.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your issue? are you getting an error when running the code? It's not doing what you want? if so, what is it that its not doing? We need more details. I suspect that your `VLookUp` is throwing an error?

Comment: I am trying to populate the packing list based on the document number, in the screens for IB-SEP17-072-0661, I want to get all the item-1 first and their subtotal followed by a row space and then all item-2s with the subtotal. With pivot table I am not able to get all the items but a single item-1 and its total.

Comment: So far I havent been able to write a code to do the above, to get the values from ProductData sheet based on document number and then all the items with the sub-total